# Spring boot JPA hibernate one to many relationship does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and would like to create a small restful api based on spring boot.

I've set up the mysql database and connect successfully to my project. While I got trouble setting up the relationship between entities.

```
package ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.inspection;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant.Restaurant;

@Entity
public class Inspection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "inspection_id")
    private Long id;

//  @ManyToOne
//  @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")
//  private Restaurant restaurant;

    private String result;
    private String violation;
    private Date time;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Inspection [result=" + result + ", time=" + time + "]";
    } 

    protected Inspection() {
    }

    public Inspection(String result, String violation, String timeStr) {
        this.result = result;
        this.violation = violation;
        this.time = parseTime(timeStr);
    }

//  public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
//      this.restaurant = restaurant;
//  }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getViolation() {
        return violation;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    private Date parseTime(String dateStr) {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date time = null;
        try {
            time = parser.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Unparseable using " + dateStr);
        }
        return time;
    }
}
```

For each restaurant, I would like to have mutliple inspections related to that.

```
package ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.inspection.Inspection;

@Entity
public class Restaurant implements Comparable<Restaurant> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int zip;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
//  private ArrayList<Inspection> inspections;
//  private ArrayList<Crime> crimes;
    private double foodSafetyScore;
    private double neighborhoodSafetyScore;
    private double overallScore;
    private boolean closed;

//  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = Inspection.class)
//  private List<Inspection> inspections;

    protected Restaurant() {
    }

    public Restaurant(String name, int zip, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.closed = false;
        this.foodSafetyScore = 0;
        this.neighborhoodSafetyScore = 0;
    }

//  public void addInspection(Inspection ins) {
//      inspections.add(ins);
//      ins.setRestaurant(this);
//  }   

//  public List<Inspection> getInspections() {
//      return inspections;
//  }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getNeighborhoodSafetyScore() {
        return neighborhoodSafetyScore;
    }

    public double getOverallScore() {
        return overallScore;
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return isClosed();
    }

    public int compareTo(Restaurant other) {
        return Double.compare(overallScore, other.overallScore);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Restaurant [name=" + name + ", overallScore=" + overallScore + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Restaurant other = (Restaurant) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(latitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.latitude))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(longitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.longitude))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (zip != other.zip)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to do a quick test (insert some data into db) as follows:

```
package ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.inspection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant.Restaurant;
import ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant.RestaurantRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Gen implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private InspectionRepository inspectionRepo;

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gen.class, args);
    }

//  @Bean
//  public CommandLineRunner demo(InspectionRepository repository) {
//      return (args) -> {
//          Inspection i1 = new Inspection("pass", "no comment", "11/04/1998");
//          Inspection i2 = new Inspection("pass with condition", "no comment", "11/04/2019");
//          Inspection i3 = new Inspection("fail", "no comment", "11/04/2001");
//          repository.save(i1);
//          repository.save(i2);
//          repository.save(i3); 
//          System.out.println("All saved!");
//          for (Inspection ins : repository.findAll()) {
//              System.out.println(ins); 
//          }
////            Restaurant r1 = new Restaurant("asd", 100, 12.2, 12.2);
//      }; 
//  }
    @Override 
    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Restaurant r1 = new Restaurant("asd", 100, 12.2, 12.2);
        Inspection i1 = new Inspection("pass", "no comment", "11/04/1998");
        Inspection i2 = new Inspection("pass with condition", "no comment", "11/04/2019");

//      r1.addInspection(i1);
//      r1.addInspection(i2);

        restaurantRepo.save(r1);
    }
}
```

However I change the code by searching through all the answers,
I always got the error message when I run my spring application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.inspection.Inspection.restaurant references an unknown entity: ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant.Restaurant
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lamb
```

......

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.inspection.Inspection.restaurant references an unknown entity: ca.mcmcaster.xb3l02g06.DineSafeChicago.restaurant.Restaurant
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1658) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Really appreciate any helpful hints!

Comment: Where is @OneToMany annotation in Entity Table which you want to link to other??

Comment: Hi, the commented out code is the relationship I would like to build. Each restaurant should map to many inspections.